# Sending single commands to a maya node

Tags: python, real-time, maya

I'm planning on creating a maya node that pulls some input from a serial port or some other kind of real time input. Each time I wish to receive input I must have an open connection to a unix file like unix, so far so simple.

My question is this, how do I send the maya node a one time command like `connect` or `disconnect`. I only know how to set up a simple 'attribute effects' stye relationship between attributes which isn't quite right for this situation. The only solution i could think of would be to add a non animatable boolean attribute to the node and run the `connect` `disconnect` methods whenever that attribute was changed, does this seem like a sensible solution?

Comment: Are you sure you want to do this at the node level? Maya already exposes the command port, which would provide a global input-output tcp connection to which you can push data and which will trigger a callback. If you do it with nodes you'll have to worry about things like artists accidentally duplicating objects and triggering a fight over the file on disk, etc.  Nodes in general don't have event hooks you can grab.You could try triggering this from a scriptJob, but at that point the node is almost superfluous...  What's the application?

Comment: Interesting, I'll look into it. I want to create an interface for the playstation sixaxis controller which seems simple enough

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your goal is to support an external controller, there are a lot of examples on the net that use the commandport as an interface to external controllers. The clockServer example that comes with the Maya SDK shows how it can be done; and as an example of how to conver that into  There's also  Dave Moore's hacked up Xbox 360 controller server based on the clock server [here](http://onepartcode.com/projects/ControllerServer.cpp) that might give you an idea how to tackle it.

Comment: sounds just the ticket, unfortunately im developing on a mac and the device editor is unavailable for mac

Comment: Oh, that makes life much harder.  I don't know if OSX will support MPxMidiInputDevice (http://download.autodesk.com/us/maya/2011help/API/class_m_px_midi_input_device.html) or if that's removed too...